# generator of sigma algebra associated with stopping time

Tags: probability, random-variables, martingales, stopping-times, filtrations

I am studying Martingales and Stopping Times from the 3rd edition of the book "Probability and Measure" by Patrick Billingsley. The following arose while I was reading page 465.

Let $(\varOmega,\mathscr{F},\mathsf{P})$ be a probability space, let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables on $(\varOmega,\mathscr{F})$, and set $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\;\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(X_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$. Suppose that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a martingalge relative to the filtration $(\mathscr{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and let $\tau\colon\varOmega\to\mathbb{N}$ be a stopping time relative to $(\mathscr{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Set 
$$\mathscr{F}_\tau=\left\{A\in\mathscr{F}\;\mid\;
(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\;A\cap\left[\tau=n\right]\in\mathscr{F}_n\right\},
$$
where $\left[\tau=n\right]=\left\{\omega\in\varOmega\;\mid\;\tau(\omega)=n\right\}$.

I am interested in finding a subset $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathscr{F}_\tau$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathscr{F}_\tau$. 
In particular,
since it is easy to show that
$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\quad
\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma\Bigg(\left\{\bigcap_{i=0}^nX_i^{-1}(B_i)\;\mid\;
(B_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}\text{ are Borel sets in }\mathbb{R}\right\}\Bigg),
$$
**I guess:** if we set
$$
\mathcal{A}=\left\{\left[\tau=n\right]\cap\bigcap_{i=0}^nX_i^{-1}(B_i)\;\mid\;
n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }(B_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}\text{ are Borel sets in }\mathbb{R}\right\},
$$
then $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathscr{F}_\tau$.
However, I have no clue whether this is true or not. All I could check is that $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathscr{F}_\tau$.

**My question:** Is my guess correct? If so, how could I establish that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathscr{F}_\tau$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is defined above?

Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2319889/36150) is related.

Comment: Indeed, this is very helpful!!! :)